# Rails Web application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting this error even when I create a new project. I installed Ruby and RoR through RVM

```
cannot load such file -- /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger (LoadError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:74:in `init_passenger'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:155:in `<module:App>'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

I think I found that the problem is in the directory of the gems. I do not know how to change it on Ubuntu

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` from the root of your application directory?

Comment: Yes I ran bundle install

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to understand if you have a problem with the app or the environment.

Try to run the simplest app by:

```
rails new simple_app
```

if it doesn't work - the problem is the environment.
if it does work - probably you have some problem with the initializers or config files

Let us know how it works for you!

Comment: what about the phusion_passenger? try to use the simple webBrick server

Comment: I installed the gem and still getting the same result. I installed Ruby via RVM

Comment: which gem you installed? you mean WebBrick? it comes with rails you shouldn't install it..

Comment: Would you please say would you mean with trying webrick? I never heard about it before

Comment: WeBrick is the default web server that comes with rails. you can read about it more in here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server#what-is-webrick
As it is your first app, I strongly suggest you to follow this tutorial on how to create your first app: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: I think the problem is, I cannot find this folder ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger  in passenger directory, although I installed passenger gem

Comment: don't use passenger, try to start with Webrick

Answer (score 0):

Have you try gem install passenger ?

or gem install bundler

Answer (score 0):

Your error message:

```
cannot load such file -- /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger (LoadError)
```

Suggests a permission problem with files in the gem `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30`. Either, the files **don't exist**, or they **aren't readable**.

If you query the permissions for that file (make sure to append '.rb'):

```
ls -l /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger.rb
```

You'll probably find it's not world readable, or at least not readable by the web server process' user. If it doesn't exist, then you should reinstall.

I saw this error on a system that had a umask of `0066`, which caused passenger's gem files to be root:root with mode -rw-------.